# How to list all AD LDS instances using c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, active-directory, windows-server-2008, adlds

I know that I can view all the AD LDS instances running on my server through dsdbutil command line tool. But I want to know how I can list all the instances running on my server computer through C++. Please this thing drives me crazy.